# Python - How to Search for a Value in a Dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, web-scraping, nested

I am downloading Yahoo Finance statistics data and the resulting output is a Python nested dictionary.
Basically I need to look for 'enterpriseValue' and 'trailingPE' inside of the nested dictionary.

This will exist in the output - 'enterpriseValue'.

This will not - 'trailingPE'.

I need to identify the non-existent items so that I can bypass them and keep processing the data.

I have been trying to get the following code block to work below.
However, I haven't had any luck yet.

Everything seems to work until I call the recursive lookup function.

The current code cannot find 'enterpriseValue' or 'trailingPE'.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests, re, json, pprint, datetime

p = re.compile(r'root\.App\.main = (.*);')

tickers = ['APT.AX']

results = {}

dict_searchFor = {
    'Enterprise_Value' : 'enterpriseValue'
    , 'Trailing_PE' : 'trailingPE'
    }

def recursive_lookup(k, d):
    if k in d:
        return d[k]
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return recursive_lookup(k, v)
    return None

with requests.Session() as s:

    for ticker in tickers:
        r = s.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/key-statistics?p={}'.format(ticker,ticker))
        data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
        d = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']
        print(d)
        for k in dict_searchFor:
            value = dict_searchFor[k] 
            print(k)
            print(value) 
            recursive_lookup(k, d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first call parameters is incorrect. Pass the value to your recursive_lookup.

```
import requests
import re
import json
import pprint
import datetime

p = re.compile(r'root\.App\.main = (.*);')

tickers = ['APT.AX']

results = {}

dict_searchFor = {
    'Enterprise_Value': 'enterpriseValue', 'Trailing_PE': 'trailingPE'
}


def recursive_lookup(k, d):
    if k in d:
        return d[k]
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return recursive_lookup(k, v)
    return None


with requests.Session() as s:

    for ticker in tickers:
        r = s.get(
            'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/key-statistics?p={}'.format(ticker, ticker))
        data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
        d = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']
        # print(d)
        for k in dict_searchFor:
            value = dict_searchFor[k]
            print(k)
            # print(value)
            print(recursive_lookup(value, d))
```

Comment: Hi Pramote. I tried your method and it worked great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use the "get" method of dictionary. You can assign a value in case the searched key does not exist:

```
value = dict_searchFor.get(k,0)
if value:
    ## do something... This will not be accessed if value == 0 (key does not exist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that you in the `recursive_lookup()` return the result of the first dict search, even if it's None.

I believe this version should work as intended:

```
def recursive_lookup(needle, haystack):
    for key, value in haystack.items():
        if key == needle:
            return value
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            nested_value = recursive_lookup(needle, value)
            if nested_value:
                return nested_value
```

If you're on Python 3.8 or later, you can shorten this using an assignment expression.

```
def recursive_lookup(needle, haystack):
    for key, value in haystack.items():
        if key == needle:
            return value
        if isinstance(value, dict) and nested_value := recursive_lookup(needle, value):
            return nested_value
```